# Slowing down internet connection to better understand UX on slower connections?

Tags: user-research, tools

I would like to better understand the UX on slower connections.

Is there a set of tools or instructions on how to achieve this on Mac/Windows?

FYI, my software isn't a website or app, it's desktop software that runs on Mac and Windows.

I don't mind a DIY solution even.

Comment: So it is. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536249/simulating-slow-internet-connection your answer is here on stack overflow so i'm voting to close this question.

Comment: You can also do it in developer tools in your browser. I think it's called throttling...

Comment: @RobbyReindeer I'm not surprised google has thought of it. Very cool. Thing is in this case I'm testing desktop software (it's a command line tool for mac and windows)

Comment: @RobbyReindeer It may be a "duplicate" of a post on another SE site. However, this is certainly a UX question as I see it. (Posts on different SE sites are not duplicates, AFAIK.)

Comment: @Kris I think the question is an interesting one and probably of some value to the community. But I would argue that it has little to do with the UX of slowing bandwidth and sits more as an implementation question. If it was regarding guidelines on how to conduct studies with different connection speeds then I could see your point.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

What about Chrome devTools - there is "Throttling" on "Network tab", and also there is "Performance" tab with snapshots and visualizing the sequence of rendering.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Other browsers usually have similar tools, but I found chrome best, or at least I am used to it.